# UITextView in UIScrollView is not scrollable

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in my `UIScrollView`. The `Scrollview` contains images and scrolls horizontally. The `Textview` is added as a subview and contains some text. Sometimes the text is quite long, so I want the textview to be scrollable. Here is what I do:

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 490, 280, 86)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:63.0f/255.0f  green:154/255.0f blue:201/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [textView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280, 400)];
```

Problem is, I cannot scroll.

Is it possible, that the scrollview eats my touches? What would be a clean solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollViews have a bolean property called `delaysContentTouches`. By default, this is set to `YES` - it tells the scroll view to delay passing on touch events to its subviews.

This is why currently your text view doesn't scroll. If you set `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` you will hopefully find your text view now working.

Comment: actually, it wasn'r quite like this. What  did b4 was: create UIImageView, create UITextView, add Textview to Imageview, add the whole thing to UIScrollview. I changed it to: create Imageview and add to scrollV, create Textview, add to scrollview. It works now, but I would like to know why - do you know maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I've put horizontal-only UISCrollViews in a vertical-only UIScrollView. That works fine. But if the parent and child UISCrollView both support scrolling in the same direction, I could see that being a problem. You may need to sub-class UIScrollView and override touch events and dispatch them appropriately (to the parent or child, depending on what you want to happen, where the touch is, etc)