# iPhone - scrollview with a textview and tableview inside

Tags: iphone, textview, scrollview, tableview

I have an interface which will have a text view and a table view below it. My current view looks like this

UIScrollView

- UITextView
- UITableView

Currently the TextView and TableView can scroll vertically..but what i want is the whole screen to scroll up/down. Why doesn't this work properly?

Comment: Have you tried the SO search function?

Comment: yes i have tried. All i found was you should never put a table view inside a scroll view. I didn't find anything that answered my problem though

Comment: In that case you should enhance your question with the well known remedies and explain why they did not work for you. Check for example the use of delaysContentTouches from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967756/uitextview-in-uiscrollview-is-not-scrollable

Comment: And yes, never put a UITableView into a UIScrollView :D

Comment: thanks for the advice but this link talks about just a textview, which has scrolling properties. Scrolling isn't the problem. I wish to have the whole view scroll instead of having the individual views scroll (i.e the textview and tableview)

Comment: ok i have solved it. you use a table view controller and embedd the textviews, labels, images..etc inside the tableview

Comment: you should answer your own question then or remove it entirely to prevent unanswered questions here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a TableView inside a ScrollView, but you must resolve conflicts between touches, scrolling, and bouncing in IB or with code, and you must set the ScrollView's contentSize *with code*, not in IB.

If the TextView really "belongs" to the table, consider putting it in a table cell, or better, as a header, that's what they're for.